# Custom Error in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I have an issue to handling error in MVC. My goal is to show in the header a "friendly" error message, but the application should be already visible.
I use the override OnException on Base Controller method as following :

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        return;

    var error = new ErrorModel(filterContext.Exception);
    error.ActionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    error.ControllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

    filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorInfo"] = error;

    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction(actionName: "DisplayError", controllerName: "Error");            

    //base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

ErrorModel is a flat copy of HandleErrorInfo because all action need to be serialized.

In an ErrorController, I retrieve my model from TempData

```
public ActionResult DisplayError()
{
    var error = TempData["ErrorInfo"] as ErrorModel;
    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;

    return PartialView("Error", error);
}
```

And I call my View

```
@using log4net;
@model Easily.MVC.Utils.ErrorModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

    <link href="@string.Format("http://{0}/easily.Ressources.Web/css/easilyCommon.min.css", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EasilyServerName"])" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/custom.css")?v=@Html.Action("GetVersion", "Main")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Worklist.css")?v=@Html.Action("GetVersion", "Main")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.contextMenu.css")?v=@Html.Action("GetVersion", "Main")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> window['currentPath'] = '@Url.Content("~/")'; </script>
    <script src="@string.Format("http://{0}/easily.Ressources.Web/js/easilyCommon.min.js", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EasilyServerName"])" type="text/javascript"></script>

<fieldset class="divError">
    @if (ViewBag != null && ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <legend title="Erreur Easily.MVC" class="legendError">Une erreur s'est produite</legend>@*
         <span>Erreur Easily.MVC</span>*@
    }
    @if (Model != null /*&& HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled*/)
    {
        <legend title="Erreur @Model.Exception.Message" class="legendError">Une erreur s'est produite</legend>@*
        <span>Erreur @Model.Exception.Message</span>*@
    }

    <div class="detailError">
        <h3>Detail de l'erreur</h3>
        <div class="list-sfs-holder msgError">
            @if (ViewBag != null && ViewBag.Message != null)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-error">@ViewBag.Message</div>
            }
            @if (Model != null /*&& HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled*/)
            {
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <b>Exception:</b> @Model.Exception.Message<br />
                        <b>Controller:</b> @Model.ControllerName<br />
                        <b>Action:</b> @Model.ActionName
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <p>
                        <b>StackTrace:</b>
                    </p>
                    <div style="overflow: scroll; width: 980px;">

                            <pre>
                         @Model.Exception.StackTrace
                </pre>

                    </div>
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

@{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("WorkListError");

    if (ViewBag != null && ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        log.Error("ViewBag.Message:" + @ViewBag.Message);
    }
    if (Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        log.Error("Exception:" + Model.Exception.Message + "|" +
                   "Controller:" + Model.ControllerName + "|" +
                   "Action:" + Model.ActionName + "|" +
                   "StackTrace:" + Model.Exception.StackTrace
                 );
    }    
}

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".detailError").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content", width: '980px' });
    });

</script>
```

At least, for AJAX Error, I use this script :

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    $("#error_content").html(jqxhr.responseText);
});
```

With this code, the result is as my goal @ localhost. But when I deploy this on test server, I have server message Error 500 instead my error view. So how I can modify the code to avoid error 500 and ever catch error in custom display (server can not be modified, but I can use web.config) ? And if I comment ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500; in DisplayError, Ajax Error is not catched.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question (probably doesn't) but you can (and should, in my opinion) return a status code 500 along with your error view, instead of redirecting to an error page. That makes things a lot clearer, easier to debug and is easy to implement.

Comment: Also, you should use your logging library inside the Controller and not inside the View.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The ErrorController and BaseController are in separate common dll. The View is in project that use the dll. Next step is in integration of View in this dll and logging from this dll. But it will be in another StackOverflow question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `web.config`, make sure you have the following configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The default value for `errorMode` is `DetailedLocalOnly` ([docs](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors))